# How do I correctly check for crypt() with CMake?

Tags: c, cmake

First of all, please don’t lecture me about using `crypt()` – I know what it does and what it does not.  I have a little C program that is supposed to use the very `crypt()` that the OS is using to check user passwords (assuming it does, I know OpenBSD does not).

However, `crypt()` is a little different in every libc: some require `unistd.h`, some require `crypt.h`, some require no extra libraries, some require `-lcrypt`.  And there’s libxcrypt as well, which is starting to replace glibc’s long deprecated `crypt()`.

Long story short: I’m new to CMake, and while checking for something with `FindSomething.cmake` or pkg-config is easy, checking for which demons to invoke for libc `crypt()` is not, and I feel like I’m doing it wrong.  It works, but looks way too complicated.

Also, I’d like to try using libxcrypt if `crypt()` wasn’t found with other methods.  How can I do that without repeating half the checks?

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.10)
project(pwhash)

set(USE_LIBXCRYPT OFF CACHE BOOL "Use libxcrypt for crypt()")

find_package(PkgConfig REQUIRED)

add_executable(pwhash pwhash.c)

if(USE_LIBXCRYPT)
  pkg_check_modules(LIBXCRYPT IMPORTED_TARGET REQUIRED libxcrypt)
  target_link_libraries(pwhash PUBLIC PkgConfig::LIBXCRYPT)
  target_compile_definitions(pwhash PUBLIC HAVE_CRYPT_H)
else()
  include(CheckIncludeFile)
  check_include_file(crypt.h HAVE_CRYPT_H)
  if(HAVE_CRYPT_H)
    list(APPEND CMAKE_REQUIRED_INCLUDES "crypt.h")
    target_compile_definitions(pwhash PUBLIC HAVE_CRYPT_H)
  endif()
  include(CheckSymbolExists)
  unset(HAVE_CRYPT CACHE)
  check_symbol_exists(crypt "unistd.h" HAVE_CRYPT)
  if(NOT HAVE_CRYPT)
    unset(HAVE_CRYPT CACHE)
    list(APPEND CMAKE_REQUIRED_LIBRARIES "crypt")
    check_symbol_exists(crypt "unistd.h" HAVE_CRYPT)
    if(HAVE_CRYPT)
      target_link_libraries(pwhash PUBLIC crypt)
    else()
      error("No crypt() found")
    endif()
  endif()
endif()
```

Comment: Can you explain the logic of your searching algorithm in plain English?

Comment: Just so you know, `error()` is not a CMake command. You're looking for `message(FATAL_ERROR "No crypt() found")`.

Answer (score 1):

> However, `crypt()` is a little different in every libc: some require `unistd.h`, some require `crypt.h`, some require no extra libraries, some require `-lcrypt`. And there’s libxcrypt as well, which is starting to replace glibc's long deprecated `crypt()`.

As far as I know, the `crypt` function is declared in `unistd.h` on all major implementations. That includes macOS, FreeBSD, OpenBSD, and Linux. The *extended set* of crypt functions, like `crypt_r`, `crypt_rn`, and `crypt_ra` are in `<crypt.h>`. I'm curious to know which libcs do not have `crypt` in `unistd.h`.

> Also, I’d like to try using libxcrypt if crypt() wasn’t found with other methods. How can I do that without repeating half the checks?

For this, we'll write a function to encapsulate each method. Each function will try to define an *interface library* `pwhash_crypt` that encapsulates the usage requirements for the `crypt()` function.

We'll start with the boilerplate:

```fortran
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.20)
project(pwhash LANGUAGES C)
```

First, we'll look at `find_libxcrypt`

```fortran
function(find_libxcrypt)
  if (TARGET pwhash_crypt)
    return()
  endif ()

  find_package(PkgConfig REQUIRED)
  pkg_check_modules(LIBXCRYPT IMPORTED_TARGET libxcrypt)

  if (TARGET PkgConfig::LIBXCRYPT)
    add_library(pwhash_crypt INTERFACE)
    target_link_libraries(pwhash_crypt INTERFACE PkgConfig::LIBXCRYPT)
    target_compile_definitions(pwhash_crypt INTERFACE HAVE_CRYPT_H)
  endif ()
endfunction()
```

This should be fairly straightforward. If the `pwhash_crypt` target does not exist, then it will try to use pkg-config to find `libxcrypt` and create `pwhash_crypt` if so. Libraries propagate their interface properties to the targets linking to them, so later when we link `pwhash` to `pwhash_crypt`, it will have `HAVE_CRYPT_H` defined.

The function for the system crypt implementation `find_sys_crypt` is similarly straightforward:

```fortran
function(find_sys_crypt)
  if (TARGET pwhash_crypt)
    return()
  endif ()

  include(CheckIncludeFile)
  include(CheckSymbolExists)

  set(defs "")
  set(CMAKE_REQUIRED_INCLUDES "")
  set(CMAKE_REQUIRED_LIBRARIES "")

  check_include_file("crypt.h" HAVE_CRYPT_H)
  if (HAVE_CRYPT_H)
    list(APPEND defs HAVE_CRYPT_H)
    list(APPEND CMAKE_REQUIRED_INCLUDES "crypt.h")
  endif ()

  check_symbol_exists(crypt "unistd.h" HAVE_CRYPT)
  if (NOT HAVE_CRYPT)
    list(APPEND CMAKE_REQUIRED_LIBRARIES crypt)
    check_symbol_exists(crypt "unistd.h" HAVE_CRYPT_WITH_LIB)
  endif ()

  if (HAVE_CRYPT OR HAVE_CRYPT_WITH_LIB)
    add_library(pwhash_crypt INTERFACE)
    target_link_libraries(pwhash_crypt INTERFACE ${CMAKE_REQUIRED_LIBRARIES})
    target_compile_definitions(pwhash_crypt INTERFACE ${defs})
  endif ()
endfunction()
```

This follows the same structure as the previous function and the checks in your question.

Then you can give users an option whether to look for `libxcrypt` first or second and then link the result to your `pwhash` executable:

```fortran
option(PREFER_LIBXCRYPT "Prefer libxcrypt for crypt()" OFF)
if (PREFER_LIBXCRYPT)
  find_libxcrypt()
  find_sys_crypt()
else ()
  find_sys_crypt()
  find_libxcrypt()
endif ()

if (NOT TARGET pwhash_crypt)
  message(FATAL_ERROR "Could not find a suitable crypt() implementation")
endif ()

add_executable(pwhash pwhash.c)
target_link_libraries(pwhash PRIVATE pwhash_crypt)
```